# laravel spatie issue with lada-cache

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel spatie producing issue with lada-cache.
It seems it is taking wrong instance to execute query.

```
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
    file: "/var/www/html/project-name/vendor/spiritix/lada-cache/src/Spiritix/LadaCache/Reflector.php"
    line: 126
    message: "Argument 1 passed to Spiritix\LadaCache\Reflector::getTablesFromWhere() must be an instance of Spiritix\LadaCache\Database\QueryBuilder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given, called in /var/www/html/project-name/vendor/spiritix/lada-cache/src/Spiritix/LadaCache/Reflector.php on line 145"
    
    Package Information :
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.9",
    "spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering": "^1.1",
    "spiritix/lada-cache": "^3.0".    



 Even I am getting the same result after updating the package.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.